# Error when programming Python in Eclipse with plug-in PyDev

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, pydev

I am trying to program Python (3.2) in Eclipse with plug-in PyDev.

```
  Eclipse Standard/SDK
  Version: Kepler Service Release 2
  Build id: 20140224-0627
```

On win 7, I have installed Eclipse from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

I have also configured PyDev based on the instructions [here](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm)

But, whenever I create a new project and begin to type python code in Eclipse, the Eclipse becomes "not responding" and the whole IDE turns gray. Then, I have to close it and restart Eclipse.

This is the only one application that I have opened.

The CPU and memory usage of the desktop are also normal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have download the right version of Eclipse and PyDev?

Comment: yes, i can run a simple "hello world" program. But, when I type code by using some shortcut such as ctrl+space for some built-in functions of a package such as numpy, I got the problem. And also I got the problem if I type the built-in functions after the package name such as import numpy as np, np.a_function_name. thanks !